# It appears that retransformClasses removes user defined attributes(?) How can I add notes to a method that are preserved through retransformation?

Tags: java, jvm, instrumentation

As part of our instrumentation tool suite, we have a static prepass that modifies some methods of a class and then marks those methods with a user defined attribute. When the application is run, if the class file is presented directly to the the transform() method, i.e. it is the first load of the class, I can see these attributes.  But if I use retransformClasses(), then when I get control in at the transform() method my attributes have been deleted.  I can see why the JVM might discard unknown attributes when recreating the class bytes to pass to transform(), but I cannot find any documentation verifying and/or describing this behavior.

How can I accomplish this goal?  I can see no guarantee that the same does not happen for RuntimeVisible annotations.  And even if they are preserved, they are so much more difficult to work with than attributes I would like to avoid that approach.

Any ideas on how to add 'notes' to a method that are preserved through retransformClasses()?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Once a class file is loaded, HotSpot JVM does not preserve the original bytecode. Instead, it [reconstitutes](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/89c44961a84f/src/hotspot/share/prims/jvmtiEnv.cpp#l430) the bytecode from the internal VM representation when needed. The attributes that VM does not understand are not restored.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#retransformClasses(java.lang.Class...)) to `retransformClasses` explicitly mentions this possibility:

> The initial class file bytes represent the bytes passed to
>   ClassLoader.defineClass or redefineClasses (before any transformations
>   were applied), however they might not exactly match them. The constant
>   pool might not have the same layout or contents. The constant pool may
>   have more or fewer entries. Constant pool entries may be in a
>   different order; however, constant pool indices in the bytecodes of
>   methods will correspond. Some attributes may not be present. Where
>   order is not meaningful, for example the order of methods, order might
>   not be preserved.

In the mean time, `RuntimeVisibleAnnotations` attribute is understood by the JVM. Moreover, there is Java API to access them, therefore JVM cannot throw them away during transformation. HotSpot JVM indeed [writes](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/89c44961a84f/src/hotspot/share/prims/jvmtiClassFileReconstituter.cpp#l118) `RuntimeVisibleAnnotations` when reconstituting the bytecode.

So, your best bet is to use annotations - after all, they are designed exactly for marking members with user-defined metadata.